# I don't get data from remote service

Tags: wcf

I have a service, hosted in a windows service. When I installed the windows service in the local machine, I can get data from the service, but when I installed the windows service in the remote computer (in the server), I don't get data.

I have tried in a internet browser to use the address of the endpoint in the server, and I get response, so I get the page that says how to use svcutil to create the proxy.

Although I get this page, I have tried to disabled the firewall in the server and in the client, but the problem persists, how I expected.

If I get response in the internet browser, wouldn't I get access to the methods of the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server side add trace listener so as to find out what error occures. Do you make use of any certification which service may not possess?

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to the origin of the problem.